# Corrupting an image file and mac photos library

Tags: corrupt

I have a scenario wherein I have to test on corrupt images and corrupt photos library on mac os. Is there anyway to deliberately corrupt an image file and photos library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's lots of tools online if you do a quick google. I don't know whether they actually work quite how you'd want them to?

E.g. https://corrupt-a-file.net/

Alternatively, could you simply attempt to use a file that isn't the correct format to simulate similar non-functional behaviour? E.g. simply rename a .txt file to a .jpg and attempt to pass that through the system?